# The connection between symmetry and classifying spaces of a group

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, topology, topological-phase

I recently read the following statement:

> "For any type of mathematical object, an object of that type
>   with $G$ symmetry “is” a map from [its classifying space] $BG$ to the space of all objects of that type".

The quote is taken from https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07950 (page 10).

To give a specific example, if $P$ denotes a group of gapped phases of matter, then maps from $BG$ to $P$ correspond to gapped phases of matter with $G$ symmetry.

Could you please explain why this is true? I am unfamiliar with the notion of classifying spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood this notion of classifying maps came into play in physics thanks to Witten and Dijkgraaf in their article https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2005/group.pdf

Here the phrase you cited comes into play since for any gauge theory with gauge group $G$ finite or flat the principal $G$-bundle of the theory is compleately determined by the homotopy class of the classifying map. In other words
\begin{equation}
 H^1(M,G) \simeq [M,BG]
\end{equation}

The clarification to you answer comes from the notion that the gauge field $A$ of $G$ is exactly defined as an element inside the cohomology
\begin{equation}
A \in H^1(M,G)
\end{equation}

In this way we can identify the classifying map with the gauge field.

This is obviously just an example, but works for higher symmetries too. I am not sure of other example to understand the statement.